# Monitor Position Adjustment

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, multiple-desktop

What I need to do is extremely simple and I normally can do this via the monitor settings menu (screen position adjustment). But i have set up a older LCD TV as a 3rd monitor and I need to adjust the screen to the left a few notches.

See the image, the Windows Start button is off to the left and you can see the desktop icons also half off the screen. Also there is a black gap on the right hand side, so just a simple slide to the right is all I need.

I tried DisplayFusion, awesome app but I couldn't find the setting, anyway, choose not to keep it on my laptop as it takes over the windows display function.

Can someone guide me to software that easily adjusts the monitor position manually?

Thankyou kindly! :)

[Screenshot of the issue, and required solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCzw2.jpg)

Comment: Is this an actual screenshot or edited? Are you sure you're using the correct resolution? Are you sure only the left side is cut off?

Comment: Have you consulted the manual for the TV? Most LCD TV's, even older models, have on-screen controls for horizontal position and for related timing. If you no longer have the manual, find it online.

Comment: @DanielB Its a screen shot but on the right hand side of the screen I see a black strip where the image is not being projected and screen shot cannot capture that strip. All i need to do is narrow the left side by a few notches and I would sacrifice the right side black strip. 


I'm looking for software that can do this, here are 11 multidisplay apps that have oodles of settings, I am hoping someone can guide me to any app that will do the adjustment to the left hand side of the screen.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik

Its an old TV and and do not have the remote, I am asking for a software solution, thanks for responding though :)

Comment: Sorry to say, but I don’t see a software for this existing. That’s such a niche thing. A monitor couldn’t do it either, because we’re not using VGA anymore. You could use the overscan compensation to add borders on all edges. Shrinking the image will make its quality worse.